# Use of "AND" operation in mapreduce

Tags: scala, riak

```
SQL- select * from table_name where userid="Kim" AND weak = 1
```

As above SQL query i would like to do same query in mapreduce. How to implement "AND" operator in my case.

```
val result = riakClient.mapReduce(USERS_BUCKET_NAME,"userID:"+userID)
      .addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"),true)
      .execute
val o = parse[List[TicketModels]](result.getResultRaw)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution and it goes like this.

```
val result = riakClient.mapReduce(USERS_BUCKET_NAME,"userID:"+userID+" AND week:"+week)
      .addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"),true)
      .execute
```